# Update A Mongo Collection Without Removing Current Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

so my issue is this: I have an example mongo collection with this data:

```json
{
"_id":"813915771067301888",
"prefix":"+",
"__v":0
}
```

And I want to be able to update the values to match the schema, the schema looks like this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const GuildConfig = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    servername: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
        required: false,
    },
    prefix: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
        required: true,
        default: '+',
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('GuildConfig', GuildConfig);
```

Is there a way I can update the collection to match the schema without loosing any data? I do not want to use something like $push, but instead some option to match the collection to the current schema's default data. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: That example data already matches the schema, how should it be updated?

Comment: The model does not contain the servername parameter, I need the model to have that.

Comment: The servername field is marked as not required.  Is it not being present in the document causing a problem?

Comment: So if I mark it as required then do .update() it should work?

Comment: What exactly should be updated?  If you retrieve the document, set the servername and save it, that should work.  If you need to do a bunch at the same time, updateMany should work.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: So, I have lots of models, but I need to update all of the models with a value. I cant do that without overriding or deleting the data.

Comment: Why not?  The update functions can set the value of a single field, and be filtered to match specific documents, if necessary.

Comment: I just need to update the model to the schema. Is that possible?

Comment: The schema is code in your application, it is not stored in the database.  If you update the code to include the optional field, you can start using it in mongoose calls.

Comment: I understand that, I just do not know how to push that update into the database. I am only 14 and only have had like 1 year of mongo experience.

Comment: That's my point, the schema is never stored in the database, so there is nothing to push.  You would only need to update the database to put the actual data in the documents.  Adding an optional field to the schema can be done without even informing the database.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for your help, I understand!